# Selecting multiple checkbox with indeterminate feature

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I am implementing a small script as on http://css-tricks.com/examples/IndeterminateCheckboxes/
but my html contain an `<a>` tag as a parent of checkbox so this is causing the problem. I am not sure how to solve it.

```
<ul>
    <li"><a href="#"><input type="checkbox" >1 </a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#"><input type="checkbox">1.1</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#"><input type="checkbox" >2 </a>
        <ul>
             <li><a href="#"><input type="checkbox" >2.1</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#"><input type="checkbox" >2.1.1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><input type="checkbox" >2.1.2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><input type="checkbox">2.1.3</a></li> 
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

My Script is

```
<script>
$(function() {
  // Apparently click is better chan change? Cuz IE?
  $('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function(e) {
  var checked = $(this).prop("checked"),
      container = $(this).parent().parent(),
      siblings = container.siblings();
  container.find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop({
      indeterminate: false,
      checked: checked
  });
 function checkSiblings(el) {
      var parent = el.parent(),
          all = true;
      console.log(parent);
      el.siblings().each(function() {
           all = ($(this).children('input[type="checkbox"]').prop("checked") === checked);
          console.log(all);
          return all;
      });

      if (all && checked) {
          parent.children('input[type="checkbox"]').prop({
              indeterminate: false,
              checked: checked
          });
          checkSiblings(parent);
      } else if (all && !checked) {
          parent.children('input[type="checkbox"]').prop("checked", checked);
          parent.children('input[type="checkbox"]').prop("indeterminate", (parent.find('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length > 0));
          //console.log("thi sis ");
          checkSiblings(parent);
      } else {
          el.parents("li").children('input[type="checkbox"]').prop({
              indeterminate: true,
              checked: false
          });
          console.log("apple");
      }
    }


    checkSiblings(container);
  });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to remove those `<a>` tags from around the inputs. You can still link the user via the inputs with jQuery if you put the link href as a data attribute of the checkbox like so:

HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" data-href="#myUrl" />
```

JS

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function() {
    location.href = $(this).data('href');  
});
```

Comment: I have another script attached to it. So <a> tag is necessary. Any further solution is welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

I found out the solution for this. The problem was that the child input boxes were hard to find.
Now the code below will work if there are  tags included on the list.

```
$(function() {
  // Apparently click is better chan change? Cuz IE?
  $('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function(e) {
  var checked = $(this).prop("checked"),
      container = $(this).closest("li"),
      siblings = container.siblings();
      container.find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop({
      indeterminate: false,
      checked: checked
  });
      if(checked)
      {
                  var value= $(this).val();
                  loadMarkers();
                  console.log(value);


      }
  function checkSiblings(el) {
      //console.log(el);
      var parent = el.parent().parent(),
          all = true;
      el.siblings().each(function() {
          return all = ($(this).children().children().closest('input[type="checkbox"]').prop("checked") === checked);
      });

      if (all && checked) {
          parent.children().children().closest('input[type="checkbox"]').prop({
              indeterminate: false,
              checked: checked
          });
          checkSiblings(parent);
      } else if (all && !checked) {
          parent.children().children().closest('input[type="checkbox"]').prop("checked", checked);
          parent.children().children().closest('input[type="checkbox"]').prop("indeterminate", (parent.find('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length > 0));
          checkSiblings(parent);
      } else {
          el.parents("li").children().children().closest('input[type="checkbox"]').prop({
```

//el.parents('input[type="checkbox"]').prop({
                  //el.parents("li").children().find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop({
                  indeterminate: true,
                  checked: false
              });
          }
        }

```
    checkSiblings(container);
  });
});
```